# dockerfile: run tool on several repositories

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a cli tool that I'm creating an E2E test suite using docker. The basic idea is in the docker container I'll build the local code and then run the tool over several public repositories. The main goal of this is to make it easier to see any missing functionality that my CLI tool may need to add.

I did manage to get it working but it's a bit of a pain to manage due to all the chaining and folder management.

```
## Build a node application
from node:8.11.1
WORKDIR /app

## Copy all the files
COPY . ./sortier

## Build run and test
RUN  cd ./sortier \
  && npm install --unsafe-perm \
  && npm run test \
  && cd .. \
## Run react-redux-typescript-guide/playground test
  && pwd \
  && git clone https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide  \
  && cd react-redux-typescript-guide/playground \
  && npm install --unsafe-perm \
  && echo "{ isHelpMode: true }" > .sortierrc \
  && cd ../../sortier \
  && npm run start -- "../react-redux-typescript-guide/playground/src/**/*.ts" \
  && npm run start -- "../react-redux-typescript-guide/playground/src/**/*.tsx" \
  && cd ../react-redux-typescript-guide/playground \
  && npm run build \
  && cd ../.. \
## Run prettier test
  && pwd \
  && git clone https://github.com/prettier/prettier \
  && cd prettier \
  && npm install --unsafe-perm \
  && echo "{ isHelpMode: true }" > .sortierrc \
  && cd .. \
  && npm run start -- "prettier/src/**/*.js" \
  && cd prettier \
  && npm run build \
  && npm run test \
  && cd ..
```

I was trying to figure out how to use WORKDIR instead to change directories which would clean it up a lot but being able to reference work directories from one another didn't seem to work.

Any advice on how I can clean up this dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

And of course after I post the question I figure out the answer (do'h)

```
## Build a node application
from node:8.11.1

## Sortier creation, build and test
WORKDIR /sortier
COPY . .
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm
RUN npm run test

## react-redux-typescript-guide/playground
WORKDIR /react-redux-typescript-guide
RUN git clone https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide .
WORKDIR /react-redux-typescript-guide/playground
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm
RUN echo "{ isHelpMode: true }" > .sortierrc
WORKDIR /sortier
RUN npm run start -- "/react-redux-typescript-guide/playground/src/**/*.ts"
RUN npm run start -- "/react-redux-typescript-guide/playground/src/**/*.tsx"
WORKDIR /react-redux-typescript-guide/playground
RUN npm run build
RUN set CI=true&&npm run test

## prettier
WORKDIR /prettier
RUN git clone https://github.com/prettier/prettier
WORKDIR /prettier
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm
RUN echo "{ isHelpMode: true }" > .sortierrc
WORKDIR /sortier
RUN npm run start -- "/prettier/src/**/*.js"
WORKDIR /prettier
RUN npm run build
RUN npm run test
```